# how can i add hyperlink into open word document in OleContainer

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, containers, ole

i want to use MsWord as editor for my HTML document.
i open anther form with some list of files.
i want the user to select one of the files
and add this as alink in the open document (at the place the user select)

i open HTML document in word created in olecontainer.
with :
      with OleContainerFrame do
      begin
        OleContainer1.CreateObjectFromFile(FileToEditName{myfile.html}, False);
        OleContainer1.AutoActivate := aaGetFocus;
        OleContainer1.DoVerb(ovOpen);
        OleContainer1.Run;
      end;

how can i add this link, as :
AddHperyLink(SomeText,TheHyperLink)....
at the place the user select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a TEdit on your form which contains a URI (I used the BBC's site).  Then the following code will add a hyperlink to it in the active Word document in your OLEContainer:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OleContainer1.OleObject.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(
  Anchor := OleContainer1.OleObject.Selection.Range,
  Address := Edit1.Text,  // contains e.g. http://www.bbc.co.uk
  TextToDisplay := 'Link'
  );
end;
```

The way this works is that OleContainer1.OleObject is a variant reference to Word.Application (see e.g. the Word2000.Pas unit that comes with Delphi) and once you have this reference you can call Word's automation methods using late (or early) binding.

Btw the unusual syntax of the arguments to OleContainer1.OleObject.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add is a special syntax that Delphi supports to enable named parameters to be used in latebound calls.

**Update:**  You say in a comment that you have tried the code above but get the error "Method 'Selection' not supported by automation object".  When I put together my test project, I didn't have an association set up between HTML and MS Word, so I write the code necessary to activate Word and load an HTML file into it.  I do this in the FormCreate event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  V : OleVariant;
  AFileName : String;
begin
  OleContainer1.CreateObject('Word.Application', False);
  OleContainer1.Run;
  V := OleContainer1.OleObject;
  Caption := V.Name;
  V.Visible := True;
  AFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Hello.Html';
  V.Documents.Add(AFileName);
end;
```

Note that this and Button1Click are the **entire code** of my project and it inserts the link as you asked.  If you get a different result, I think it must be because of some detail of your set-up that we readers can't see.

Comment: hi, thanks. i tried that. but i get "Method 'Selection' not supported by automation object"          on 
          if CatalogRec.Found then
          begin
            NewFile := StringReplace(CatalogRec.Mz_FileName,'\','/',[rfReplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);

            OleContainer1.OleObject.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(
              Anchor := OleContainer1.OleObject.Selection.Range,
              Address := NewFile,  // contains e.g. http://www.bbc.co.uk
              TextToDisplay := selectDocumentFrm.TypedHyperText
              );
          end;

Comment: for now i change the order to :            OleContainer1.OleObject.Application.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(
              Anchor := OleContainer1.OleObject.Application.Selection.Range,
              Address := NewFile,  // contains e.g. http://www.bbc.co.uk
              TextToDisplay := selectDocumentFrm.TypedHyperText
              );
and it work. Thanks for your help

Comment: See the update to my answer and please say whether it works for you.

Comment: Also, please be so kind as to accept this answer by clicking the "tick" icon on its left, so that future readers will see that it answered what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

yes that work.
i didnot now we can use

`(Anchor := ....
);`

but now
word remove the execet PATH and change it to 'href="../../../../MzIAI/Images/2019-06/12/45545_5679.Pdf">'
and remove full path